# Jboss 7.X application server on mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos, jboss7.x, server

I am currently trying to set up the jboss server and every time I use the command ./standalone.sh to start it....I end up with the following results.

```
jamess-iMac:bin jameslockhart$ ls
add-user.bat        domain.conf     jconsole.sh     standalone.sh
add-user.sh     domain.conf.bat     jdr.bat         vault.bat
appclient.bat       domain.sh       jdr.sh          vault.sh
appclient.conf      init.d          run.bat         wsconsume.bat
appclient.conf.bat  jboss-cli.bat       run.sh          wsconsume.sh
appclient.sh        jboss-cli.sh        standalone.bat      wsprovide.bat
client          jboss-cli.xml       standalone.conf     wsprovide.sh
domain.bat      jconsole.bat        standalone.conf.bat
jamess-iMac:bin jameslockhart$ ./standalone.sh
=========================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /Users/jameslockhart/desktop/apps/jboss

JAVA:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
19:08:17,223 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
19:08:17,362 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
19:08:17,400 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

All the tutorials I have watched have it going beyond the "Brontes" starting. Mine just sits there. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in JBoss 7.1.1 that prevented it from starting on JDK8. JBoss AS7 is extremely outdated, you need to either use JDK7, or ideally upgrade to a recent version of Wildfly or JBoss EAP.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I was able to fix by using wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download wildfly and the system works flawlessly. Thanks for the help everyone.